# Is there a difference between piezo ceramic disc transducer and a piezo ceramic bender

Tags: sensors, ultrasound

I really do apologise if this is a stupid question but I for the life of me can't find an answer. I need to do a project where I measure the liquid of water in a tank using ultrasound and am planning on doing it with Texas Instruments TDC1000.

The problem I'm having is that I can't find the ultrasonic transducers that they use in their examples in my country and was thinking I could maybe just use one similar to it. However I can only find ceramic benders. I would just like to know if they are the same and if not what is the difference.

Thanks

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I'm in South Africa

Comment: The disc shaped ceramic benders are generally used for audio frequencies so might not be effective at the higher ultrasonic frequencies. However, they are cheap so you could try them. Otherwise, there are companies that sell to South Africa so perhaps contact them? Try: https://www.physikinstrumente.com/en/ or perhaps: https://www.mouser.co.za/Sensors/_/N-5gej?keyword=ultrasonic%20transducer

Answer (score 1):

So, the difference between both is their working and the mode of excitation. the bender piezo shall be loaded in cantilever (better for application with higher loads) less accuracy. While the disk transducer is better accuracy with lower stroke.
I feel like this is correct. Look at the product specifications to be sure. Thanks.